# How to send messages with Whatsapp Business API with ASP.NET

Tags: whatsapp

I have searched for the Whatsapp Business API but not found the official Whatsapp business API samples. What are the limitations of media messages and billing. If any one have information please provide.

Answer (score 0):

The WhatsApp Business API Client supports a subset of the features provided by the WhatsApp applications you already know from Android, iOS, Web and other platforms including end-to-end encryption. The difference is that this application can be deployed on a server, providing a local API that allows you to programmatically send and receive messages and integrate this workflow with your own systems (CRMs, customer care, etc.).

You can check the media functionalities [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media). Also, you can start with the official [doc](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api).